# Error with a loop that copy data and delete row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, row

I wrote a script to find duplicate values in Colomn B. They can be alot of duplicates :

Value1
Value2
Value3
Value1
Value2

But never more than twice. I need to get the values from C column to M column from the second duplicate of B column and paste it on the first duplicate C to M column. After, i need to delete the second duplicate row.

The script work only for one instance of duplicate..

```
Sub hi()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lastRow = Range("B100").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For iCntr = 6 To lastRow
    If Cells(iCntr, 2) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 2), Range("B1:B" & lastRow), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
        
            Cells(iCntr, 3).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Cells(iCntr, 4).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Cells(iCntr, 5).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 5).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            
            Cells(iCntr, 6).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 6).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            
            Cells(iCntr, 7).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 7).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            
            Cells(iCntr, 8).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 8).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Cells(iCntr, 9).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 9).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            
            Cells(iCntr, 10).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 10).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Cells(iCntr, 11).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 11).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            
            Cells(iCntr, 12).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 12).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            
            Cells(iCntr, 13).Copy
            Cells(matchFoundIndex, 13).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete
            
       End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Can you please help me clean this script ! Thank you !

Comment: From the question I understand that the range of **the second duplicate** should be copied to the first occurrence row, but from the code it exactly viceversa... Then, in order to delete row during such an iteration, the iteration should be done backwards, or better create a `Union` range and delete its rows at the end. Otherwise, deleting a row, the next ones looses their correct reference.

Comment: I am pretty new to this .. i think you are right because values get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the next code. It uses a dictionary to keep the row of the first occurrence and copy the range C:M of the second occurrence to the first one. It does it without selecting, without using clipboard, in a fast way. All second occurrence cells are placed in a union range and deleted at the end, at once. In fact, the actual code only selects the rows containing the second occurrence. **If it returns as you need, you only have to replace `Select` with `Delete` in the last code line**:

```
Sub hi()
    Dim lastRow As Long, iCntr As Long, rngDel As Range, dict As Object
    
    lastRow = Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For iCntr = 6 To lastRow
      If cells(iCntr, 2) <> "" Then
          If Not dict.Exists(cells(iCntr, 2).value) Then
              dict.Add cells(iCntr, 2).value, iCntr 'the first occurrence row as item
          Else
              'copy the C:M range to the row of the first occurrence
              Range("C" & dict(cells(iCntr, 2).value) & ":M" & dict(cells(iCntr, 2).value)).value = _
                                                                      Range("C" & iCntr & ":M" & iCntr).value
              If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                  Set rngDel = cells(iCntr, 2)
              Else
                  Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, cells(iCntr, 2))
              End If
          End If
    End If
 Next
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Select 'if selected what you need, replace Select with Delete
End Sub
```

The above code copies the rows of **the second occurrence** (C:M) to the row of the first one. Otherwise, it will not make any sense to copy anything on rows to be deleted...

Comment: Hi, its almost working.. the values dont get deleted and the first line of data (6) dont get the values from C:M of his duplicate.

Comment: the first occurrence dont get the value from the second occurrence ** (line 6) when you run the script you can see it get instantly deleted. all the other first occurrence get the values from the second occurrence. But no rows get deleted at the end.

Comment: But are they selected?

Comment: @pharsyde Please, carefully reread the answer words part, from the answer beginning. What do you understand from "**If it returns as you need, you only have to replace `Select` with `Delete` in the last code line**" and "**'if selected what you need, replace Select with Delete** - the comment of the last code line? Should I replace `Select` with `Delete`?

Comment: Its working, it was a error with an other macro. thank you !

Comment: @pharsyde I cannot imagine "an error with another macro", but I am glad that it works as you need. Now, I would like to tell you that we here, when somebody answers our question, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. And our main goal here is to make as many people as possible learning...